# How can I take value from select tag and give to parametres to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, button, tags

I want to give like a parameters to javascript function. And in function displayed telephone numbers by parameters

```
<select>
    <option value="name-kate">Kate</option>
    <option value="name-john">John</option>
</select>

<button onclick="getNumber()"> Show me number </button>

<p id="numbers"</p>

<script>
  function getNumber(){

var x = document.getElementById("value-number").value
document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML=x
  }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no element with an id of `value-number` in your HTML!

Comment: so mr @DhavalMarthak How can I use this select's tag for javascript function? where I have to put id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right:

```js
function getNumber(phoneNumber){
    var x = document.getElementById("value-number").value;
    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML=phoneNumber;
}
```

```html
<select id="value-number">
    <option value="name-kate">Kate</option>
    <option value="name-john">John</option>
</select>

<button onclick="getNumber(989283918)"> Show me number </button>

<p id="numbers"</p>
```

But I think what you want is this:

```js
function getNumber(phoneNumber){
    var x = document.getElementById("value-number").value;
    document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML=x;
}
```

```html
<select id="value-number">
    <option value="9283746">Kate</option>
    <option value="+369874521364">John</option>
</select>

<button onclick="getNumber()"> Show me number </button>

<p id="numbers"</p>
```

Comment: no, I mean when I select from picker for example Kate. In function with switch case I want displayed her number

Comment: @bekanur98 check my second code and see if works for you. I don't think you need to put a switch case, I just think that you should put the value of the select options as the number that you want to show

Comment: @bekanur98 Sure, no problem! If you think that is the right answer, please, accept it :D Thank you